# Facebook Javascript SDK security issue?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to embed facebook auth into my application. 
My initial effort was to login in browser and obtain code. I pass this code back to my api and obtain access token (that stays with the server) and route all my requests to FB Api through my server. Seemed totally secure to me as my client has no information to be able to make authorized calls to FB as my app.

I however have been looking at FB Javascript SDK to avoid writing code for dialog opening and closing and noticed that it allows me to `getLoginStatus` and returns me the access token. Also, I went over FB auth flows in their documentation and they say that client-server hybrid flow is okay to do where server actually gives "Long lived access token" back to the client and advises me to use HTTPS (fair).

Now all this gets me thinking if this is a security concern. Can't I as a potential hacker inject some javascript into the user's webpage that could either 
a) make a `getLoginStatus` and get the access token or 
b) just get the access token by making a request to my api server and get the access token 
and then use that to post (assuming that user authorized my app to do so) to facebook as if my app was doing it?

I am a security newbie and maybe overlooking a bunch of stuff here but could someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I do know I can enable further security to ensure that I need the app secret every time I want to make a request which the client can't do as that information will never be available on client side.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this.

Comment: @Barmar do you recommend copying it there or moving it altogether?

Comment: In general, SE doesn't like the same question on multiple sites, so it should be moved.

Comment: Understood. moving now. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Undeleting this as I am not getting any response on security stackexchange. Will really appreciate if anyone can comment on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a security expert, just some thoughts: in your question, you are assuming that the hacker somehow injects the script into the webpage in the user browser using malware and that script then interacts with the data you have client-side.

Now, if we imagine this actually happened and the evil script has full access to the web-page data, even if you don't have the access token on the client, what prevents the evil script to make requests to your server and interact with facebook through your server?

Moreover, if the user opens facebook itself and authorizes there, the evil script could be injected into facebook page and do any actions on behalf of the user, just sending the requests to facebook server.

This way, it looks for me that if the situation you describe happened, it would not really matter if you storing the access token client side or not - anyway the evil script will be able to do it's job.

Practically, if you are worried about security - first carefully check all the facebook docs related to authentication and security and follow their recommendations. Second - search for common known attack vectors and recommendations of how to avoid security risks in your application. 
If the user already has malware on his computer which is able to alter browser behavior (like inject additional scripts into pages), you probably can't do much about it.

Comment: You make some valid points. I can have more security by not letting script from a different origin talk to my api plus configure facebook to only accept requests when I send access token with the api secret(which in never intended to be on the client). I do agree with most of the stuff and am marking this as an answer. I will award the bounty to you after the 7 days have passed so that a better answer(if one is posted) gets it. Thank you for the comments. Glad to be a part of this community.

Answer (score 4):

You can only get your access token if you have a valid redirect URI which equivalent to your Site URL on your facebook application settings..

also, it needs permissions before you can post using the facebook access_token.

You can check the API calls at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Hi Rex. Thanks for the response. 
1. The redirect URI (in my opinion) is not supposed to be private and can easily be read from client side js.
2. My scenario is trying to explore after the permissions have been requested and granted.

Thanks for the link. I'll explore that.
Also, maybe my question is not clear. I'll update the question and try to add more detail to each point this evening EST.

Comment: Yes, the only way to get an access token is if you have a published application and the user allows certain permission on the API.

Comment: Yes. My concern is that with all the access granted and everything. I'm trying my best to not expose access_token to client side but the facebook Api allows you to get access token regardless if the app is authenticated. I am more worried about some malware being able to inject script that obtains access token from the api sdk and use it to do things as if my app was doing it. Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: It's really up to the user how they use their access token :)

Comment: You can try this link to get instagram accesstoken 

https://www.facebook.com/v1.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https://www.instagram.com/accounts/signup/index/&scope=email,publish_actions&response_type=token,code&client_id=124024574287414

Comment: So are we suggesting I can go out, develop a malware to distribute, figure out what apps allow payments, and try to make payments to myself? It seems unlikely to me that facebook kept that kind of hook open.
Note: I am trying to joke. Please do not take it any other way.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at instagram access token thing.

Comment: I marked the other one as an answer but I do appreciate you taking the time. Thank you. You'll get an upvote from me.